# passing values to the remote server

Tags: java, android, database, web-services

I have a server function  which consists of  username and passwords and handling functions writen in php. I want the code to send the username and password to the which are entered in the editbox to check with the username and password which was already stored in the database.

By Using the Php function in the database it's used be login in to the desired account. I just want to pass the unname and password to this function.

pls provide me with the code..

Comment: How about you start writing some code and then comeback if you have problems?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. The most simple way is to use a HTML `form` and use a PHP file as the `target`. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html).

The problem with this approach is that it sends the password unencrypted unless you use HTTPS. This means that anyone connected to the same network can read the password. Same network can be: All the people in the same cafe if you use Wifi, all the people working for the ISPs, any hacker who successfully planted a zombie in any of these networks.

So you should encrypt the password. There are two options: You can use JavaScript to [encrypt the password](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha256.html) or simply require authentication for your pages. See the manual of your web browser how to require HTTP authentication for your code.

Note that you should only save encrypted, salted passwords in your database. That way, hackers can still steal them but they are useless. Sony, for example, learned that the hard way a few weeks ago.